# How to do pivoting on this layered data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have sample data

```
declare @emp table(id int identity(1,1),E_Name varchar(20),E_company varchar(20),Emp_Val VARCHAR(10))
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Rahim','WELLS','A')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Jag','collebra',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Vasu','nunet',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Kiran','crystal',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Sajan','tiato',NULL)

insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('RAM','WELLS','A')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Srinu','Cognizant','B')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Raju','Cognizant','B')
```

Sample data :

```
    id  E_Name  E_company   Emp_Val
    1   Rahim   WELLS        A
    2   Jag     collebra    NULL
    3   Vasu    nunet       NULL
    4   Kiran   crystal     NULL
    5   Sajan   tiato       NULL
    6   RAM     WELLS        A
    7   Srinu   Cognizant    B
    8   Raju    Cognizant    B
```

script :

```
SELECT [WELLS],[Cognizant],[NULL] from (
select E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val from @emp)T
PIVOT (MAX(E_Name)FOR E_company IN([WELLS],[Cognizant],[NULL]))PVT
```

output :

```
   WELLS    Cognizant   NULL
    Rahim   Srinu      collebra
    RAM     Raju       tiato
    NULL    Srinu      crystal
    NULL    NULL       NUNET
```

Comment: How do you have three values under Cognizant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when e_company = 'WELLS' then e_name end) as wells,
       max(case when e_company = 'Cognizant' then e_name end) as cognizant,
       max(case when e_company not in ('WELLS', 'Cognizant') then e_name end) as nulls       
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when e_company in ('WELLS', 'Cognizant') then e_company end) order by id) as seqnum
      from @emp e
     ) e
group by seqnum
order by seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=388db6e792a18f86d95e64ca02235a70) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: thanks for the answer @gordon if i want to make it dynamic what i need to do instead of mentioning WELLS ans cognizant ..sometimes like IBM,Accenture and rest other companies

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is in the last select statement, it should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
from (
select * from @emp)T
PIVOT (MAX(Emp_Val)FOR E_company IN([WELLS],[Cognizant],[NULL]))PVT
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a self join within the pivot to enumerate the companies with multiple employes and values. It then uses a right join back on to the table to enumerate the companies that do not have those employees. The difference in the output is that all of the null permutations are preserved. Other than that this should cover what you are looking for.

```
declare @emp table(id int identity(1,1),E_Name varchar(20),E_company 
varchar(20),Emp_Val VARCHAR(10))
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Rahim','WELLS','A')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Jag','collebra',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Vasu','nunet',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Kiran','crystal',NULL)
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Sajan','tiato',NULL)

insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('RAM','WELLS','A')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Srinu','Cognizant','B')
insert into @emp(E_Name,E_company,Emp_Val)VALUES('Raju','Cognizant','B')


select distinct WELLS, Cognizant,case E_Company when 'Wells' then NULL when 
'Cognizant' then null else E_Company end as [NULL] from 
(
SELECT [WELLS],[Cognizant],[collebra], [nunet], [crystal], [tiato] from (
select e.E_Name,e2.E_name as E2_Name, e.E_company,e2.Emp_Val as Emp2_Val, e.Emp_Val 
from @emp e inner join @emp e2 on e.id=e2.id)T
PIVOT (MAX(E_Name)FOR E_company IN([WELLS],[Cognizant],[collebra], [nunet], 
[crystal], [tiato]))PVT) stagingtable
right join (select E_Company, E_Name from @emp) c on stagingtable.Cognizant=c.E_Name 
or stagingtable.WELLS=c.E_Name
order by 1 desc, 2 desc, 3 desc;
```